# Robot Keypress for the "control" key on mac

Tags: java, macos, keypress, awtrobot

Can anyone tell me what the Robot Keypress is for the "control" key on mac?
I've tried VK_Control, VK_META, CTRL_MASK and CTRL_DOWN_MASK still nothing.

Please note: Its the only control key on mac next to the "fn" key lefthand side. Not option or command. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL doesn't work. Can you provide a runnable example of what you gave tried?

Comment: Something else i should mention is that I am trying to have the Android Emulator rotate

`robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12);

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F12);`

Comment: Try adding a [`autoDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#setAutoDelay(int)), I've found this helps in a lot of circumstances

Comment: YES! that was it thank you sir. Pausing the thread in between methods is the trick. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I think it's code 59 - see [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100501161453/http://www.classicteck.com/rbarticles/mackeyboard.php).

Comment: Using __magic numbers__ is actually a bad idea. It may change any time, and cannot be easily read, refactored or searched.

Comment: 59 didn't not work, but great reference of keycodes. I wish it was a newer mac keyboard representation. Thanks though, close.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad to work with numeric constants. I can provide running example in Groovy, that will proof that `Robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)` is working perfectly. May it be, that you forgot call `releaseKey`?

P.S. Tested on Macos Maveric with Java 1.6 with such snippet.(Groovy)

**EDITED** (I may suppose, you need to change *Ctrl* and *F12* release order. *F12* should be released, while *Ctrl* is still pressed, then modifiers will be setted correctly, and *F12* will be treated as *Ctrl+F12*)

```
new SwingBuilder().frame(pack: true, show: true, defaultCloseOperation: JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
    textField(keyPressed: { KeyEvent e ->
        println("$e.keyCode, $e.modifiers") // prints 123 2 in response to Robot event.
        if (e.keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            new Robot().with {
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F12); // Release it first.
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}    }     }) }
```

Comment: I am using release in the keyevent, but still not getting the results i need.


`robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12);

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F12);`

Comment: @jermobileqa Answer edited. I can't check, is Android emulator get correct keystroke, but it works in other apps(checked Ctrl+O, Ctrl+S)