# Open new tab in Firefox and Chrome with Selenium is not working

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, firefox

I read a lot of options related with the way to open new windows with Selenium. All the questions and answers are from a few years ago and maybe that's why they are not working to me. And that's why I would like to open this question again.

My first approach was using javascript action:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("window.open('','NewWindow');");
```

My issue here is the different result in Firefox and Chrome. Firefox opens a new window and Chrome opens a new tab. This means that my test case is not working as expected if I executed in different browsers.

After that I think about a different approach. If I send the shortcut to open a new tab maybe both browsers will work with the same behavior. And here started my nightmare. None of the next options open anything in the current Chrome and Firefox versions:

1. Send keys concatenate the shortcut:

   ```
   getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//body")).sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND+"T");
   ```
2. Send keys multiple keys sequence:

   ```
   getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//body")).sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND,"T");
   ```
3. Send Keys chord

   ```
   getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND + "T"));
   ```
4. Using actions

   ```
   final Actions builder = new Actions(getDriver());
   builder.keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("T").perform();
   ```

I'm thinking about try with the COMMAND key Down click on any link, but maybe there is an other easy way to open a new tab in different browsers. And this is my question, do you now an efficient way to open a new tab, not a new window, in different browsers with the same action?

*ADITIONAL INFORMATION*

Selenium version -> 3.141.59

Chrome version -> 79.0.3945.79

Firefox version -> 70.0.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `executeScript("window.open('','NewWindow');")` opens a new tab with `geckodriver 0.26.0` and `Firefox  71.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a user asked how I finally solved this, my solution was this:

```
// Save the current window reference
final String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
// Look for the element I would like to click
final WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
// Create an action to be performed
final Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// The OSKEY is a global variable where depending on the OS is saved CMD or CTR
// With the special key chord, the program clicks on the element
builder.keyDown(OSKEY).click(elem).perform();
```

For me is working without browser problems.

Answer (score 2):

This may be help you:-

Using **JavascriptExecutor**:-

- Open new blank window:-

`((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('about:blank','_blank');");`

- Open new window with specific url:

`((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_blank');");`

Using **Robot class**:-

Robot class in Selenium is used for simulating keyboard and mouse events. So, in order to open a new tab, we can simulate the keyboard event of pressing `Control Key` followed by `‘t’` key of the keyboard. After the new tab gets opened, we need to switch focus to it otherwise the driver will try to perform the operation on the parent tab only.
For switching focus, we will be using `getWindowHandles()` to get the handle of the new tab and then switch focus to it.

```
//Use robot class to press Ctrl+t keys     
Robot robot = new Robot();                          
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);

//Implicit Wait
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
Thread.sleep(2000);

//Switch focus to new tab
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

//Launch URL in the new tab
driver.get("http://google.com");*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your first option was my first option and it is not working, with the same behaviour, as I mention before. And your second option I already tried but i didn't found the COMMAND (MAC) key.

Comment: I tested first then put here. Its working fine in my both browsers.

Comment: @j.barrio please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/21147675/4513879

Comment: I've had success using your `"window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_blank');"` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Two approach of Robot Class to Open url in new tab using selenium

```
public class NewTab 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/"); 

        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);

        Set<String> tabs = (Set<String>)driver.getWindowHandles();

        for(String tab : tabs)
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(tab);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            if(driver.getTitle().contains("New Tab"))
                driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

Another way, without using the for loop

```
public class NewTab {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");   

        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);

        String Base = driver.getWindowHandle();
                Set<String> tabs = (Set<String>)driver.getWindowHandles();

                tabs.remove(Base);
                driver.switchTo().window(tabs.toArray()[0].toString());
                driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.
I didn't use javascript.

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```